# Looping though an MVCArray to save Latitude and Longitude in the database

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, google-maps

I'm trying to save coordinates from a Polygon on Google Maps drawn using the Drawing Manager. But I'm having a problem looping through my latitude and longitude. I know the insert is being triggered because it is inserting the latest primary key from the parent table but the coordinates(lat and long) are not inserted at the same time. The fields just remains 'null'. Here is my attempt and I hope I explained it very well.

View(addgeofence.php)

```
google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'overlaycomplete', function(event) {
    all_overlays.push(event);

    if (event.type != google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.MARKER) {
        drawingManager.setOptions({
            drawingMode: null,
            drawingControl: false
        });
        polygonArray = event.overlay.getPath().getArray();   
    }
});

function submit()
{
    if(!Array.isArray(polygonArray) || !polygonArray.length){
        $.smallBox({
            title : "Input Alert",
            content : "<i class='fa fa-clock-o'></i> <i>There is no Polygon!</i>",
            color : "#C46A69",
            iconSmall : "fa fa-times fa-2x fadeInRight animated",
            timeout : 8000
        });
    }
    else
    {
        var stringified = JSON.stringify(polygonArray);
        formData.append('stringified', stringified);

        $.ajax({
        contentType: 'multipart/form-data',
        url: base_url+'geofence/save_geofence',
        type: "POST",
        data: formData,
        processData:false,
        contentType:false,
                    ..........
}
```

Controller(Geofence.php)

```
public function save_geofence()
{
    $qry = $this->geofence_m->save_new_geofence();
    echo json_encode($qry);
}
```

Model(Geofence_m.php)

```
public function save_new_geofence()
{
              ..............

    $gid = $this->db->insert_id();

    if($insQry)
    {
        $array = json_decode($_POST['stringified'], true);

        foreach ($array as $v1) {
            foreach ($v1 as list($a, $b)) {
                $insData = array('geofence_ID' => $gid,
                                'geofence_latitude' => $a,
                                'geofence_longitude' => $b);
                $this->db->insert('x_geofence_coordinates', $insData);    
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to insert the whole $array without being for looped and this is the inserted data:

```
[
    {"lat":22.59725475332327,"lng":113.92748227208108},
    {"lat":22.57316327618248,"lng":114.17330136387795},                
    {"lat":22.436142339776456,"lng":114.20626034825295},        
    {"lat":22.408214041987026,"lng":113.85332455723733}
]
```

UPDATE:

I'm sorry for my mistake. This is the data of $array that is being inserted when I tried to insert the $array without being for-looped. The above string is wrong, please ignore. Thanks.

```
[
    [
        {"lat":22.5642864069,"lng":113.886283542}, 
        {"lat":22.5490675872,"lng":114.206260348}, 
        {"lat":22.4069444405,"lng":114.199393893}, 
        {"lat":22.4171009278,"lng":113.88353696}
    ]
]
```

LAST UPDATE:

First Data is the correct one. I don't know how I got the second data but the Drawing Manager's event.overlay.getPath().getArray(); coordinates is the first one. And ZerosAndOnes' first answer is the solution for my case. Thanks.

Comment: It would be helpful to provide an example of the $array ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Update:

```
[
    [
            {"lat":22.5642864069,"lng":113.886283542}, 
            {"lat":22.5490675872,"lng":114.206260348}, 
            {"lat":22.4069444405,"lng":114.199393893}, 
            {"lat":22.4171009278,"lng":113.88353696}
    ]
]
```

Is an array of array, where the inner array is an array of objects. Assuming the first array always only contains the single array

```
[
    {"lat":22.5642864069,"lng":113.886283542}, 
    {"lat":22.5490675872,"lng":114.206260348}, 
    {"lat":22.4069444405,"lng":114.199393893}, 
    {"lat":22.4171009278,"lng":113.88353696}
]
```

with `json_decode($_POST['stringified'], true);` the values can be obtained by looping as

```
//Assuming the first array always contains a single array
foreach ($array[0] as $v1)
{
    $insData = array('geofence_ID' => $gid,
                    'geofence_latitude' => $v1["lat"],
                    'geofence_longitude' => $v1["lng"]);
    $this->db->insert('x_geofence_coordinates', $insData);
}
```

---

For future use `print_r($arrayOrObject)` or `var_dump($arrayOrObject)` to get a better idea about the array or object's structure.

---

#### Original Answer:

> [list() only works on numerical arrays and assumes the numerical
>   indices start at 0.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.list.php)

The `$array` is an Array of Objects (uses {} instead of []) not an Array of Arrays.
Thus `$a` and `$b` in `list($a, $b)` will be empty.

As it's an Array of Objects, you can alter your foreach as below to access the `lat` and `lng` properties of the objects.

```
foreach ($array as $v1) {
            $insData = array('geofence_ID' => $gid,
                            'geofence_latitude' => $v1->lat,
                            'geofence_longitude' => $v1->lng);
            $this->db->insert('x_geofence_coordinates', $insData);    
    }
```

Comment: Hi. Thank you so much for your help but I still can't insert the coords. Where can I see the output of print_r() or var_dump() when I put it in the "model" like in my case the "Geofence_m.php"? And I'm also editing it in Cpanel. Will the structure of my $array = json_decode($_POST['stringified'], true); change if I $encoded = json_encode([$array]); it? I used json_encode() so that I can insert it as a string and view the contents.The data above is the result of $array = json_decode($_POST['stringified'], true); $encoded = json_encode($array);. Maybe that's the reason I still can't insert.

Comment: For temporary debugging in save_new_geofence replace $_POST['stringified'] with the above $array string, and then call save_new_geofence by accessing it on base_url/geofence/save_geofence. See what that displays and debug accordingly. Because, for the current given $array the above should work.
 
Additionally, json_encode([$array]) shouldn't be an issue, as long as json_decode($_POST['stringified', true) is used, since the second parameter will return the data as associative array for objects.

Comment: Hi, I was testing in phpfiddle with my first data(first data is the correct one) and your first answer. And I was able to echo and var_dump() the coords. I tried inserting it in the database and it did. The reason is I forgot to include the second parameter 'true' on json_decode(). If I included the second parameter 'true', phpfiddle says "E_NOTICE : type 8 -- Trying to get property of non-object" pointing at $v1->lat and $v1->lng. Why is the second parameter 'true' causing the error? Anyways, thank you so much for your help.

Comment: The second parameter if passed as true, will turn the objects (if any) into  associative arrays. Arrays don't have properties thus $v1->lat or $v1->lng will throw an error. Instead, arrays have keys/indexes, therefore, $v1["lat"] or $v1[0] will work in this case. 

If true is not passed as 2nd parameter, then the object will remain an object, and it will have properties, which can be accessed like $object->propertyName etc.